# Function in python that outputs either -1 or 0 or 1

Tags: python, function, if-statement, rounding

Is there like a (modified) round function where the output would be either -1,0,1 depending on to what number is the input the closest? E.g. *0 => 0, -2154 => -1, 10 => 1*

Currently I am using normal if else statements:

```
if i == 0:
    return 0
elif i > 0: 
    return 1
else:
    return -1
```

But is there any way how I can make this a one-line code? By for instance using some modified round function.

Comment: Do you also want to support decimal numbers?

Comment: no need to, all the input numbers will be integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `numpy.sign()`

```
import numpy as np

print(np.sign(1.2))
print(np.sign(-3.4))
print(np.sign(0))
```

output:

```
1.0
-1.0
0
```

Without any imports:

```
def sign(i):
    return (i>0) - (i<0)
    
print(sign(1))
print(sign(-3))
print(sign(0))
```

output:

```
1
-1
0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you know if there is any way of doing this without using imported libraries at all?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner function using plain vanilla python and no imports. It can hardly get simpler than this.

```
def f(i):
    return -1 if i < 0 else int(bool(i))


In [5]: f(0)
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: f(1)
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: f(-5)
Out[7]: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer commented, you can do it easily by using the `numpy.sign()` method, that directly returns your desired result.

However, you can do it directly using the built-in math function and the method `copysign(x, y)`, which copies the sign of the second value to the first. By setting the first value as a boolean it will be interpreted as 0 if the original value is 0, and 1 otherwise. Then we copy the sign of value, which will transform the 1 into -1 or leave it positive.

```py
from math import copysign

values = [1, 200, 0, -3, 45, -15]

for value in values:
    print(int(copysign(bool(value), value)))
```

which outputs:

```
1
1
0
-1
1
-1
```